# How to raise a validation event from a key press

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to raise the:

```
private void txtbox_startdate_Validating(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {}
```

Function from a key leave event.  The leave event looks like:

```
private void txtbox_startdate_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {}
```

The trouble is of course if I try and call it in this manner:

```
txtbox_startdate_Validating(sender, e)
```

An error is raised because in this case `e` is an `EventArg`s whereas the validation function wants a `System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs` and so, how do I convert `EventArgs` to a `System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs` or create one so that I can call my validation function?

Comment: I do actually have a way around it, by obviously throwing the exception and in this case ignoring it, but I was wondering if there was a more 'elegant' solution, or something!

Answer (score 1):

See MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validating.aspx

You have no need to call the `txtbox_startdate_Validating` event (or any other control with a validating event) from the `txtbox_startdate_Leave` event as it's the order of the events to go from one to another as part of the design.

Answer (score -1):

normally whatever the validator is, you can just call Validate() on it instead of doing this.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator.validate.aspx

Otherwise, just 'new' the canceleventargs yourself - it's not special, the constructors are public.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.canceleventargs.canceleventargs.aspx

Comment: Winforms question - webforms validators don't apply.